# Reading in Two Files at the Same Time (segmentation fault) c++

Tags: c++, arrays, io

This code should read in two .dat files that are in the format:

x y intensity
e.g:

```
1 1 70
1 2 0.3
1 3 5
```

It will read in one file and display the correct information and the same with the other file, but when I try and read in two files I get a "segmentation fault" despite it compiling correctly. I'm not 100% sure why since when doing one file at a time, it works so I think it may not like the way I read in the files. Once I can have this working, I will transfer to vectors but I'm still learning about them and want to nail arrays first.

```
int main()
{

  std::ifstream file1("p001_1.dat");

  std::ifstream file1_2("p001_2.dat");

    double intensity;
    int i;
    int j;
    double pic1[1392][1040]; //number of pixels
    double pic1_2[1392][1040];

    // reads in file creating an array [x][y] = intensity

    cout<<"Reading in: file1"<<endl;

    if (file1.is_open())
      {
        file1.seekg(0);
        while (!file1.eof())
          {
          file1 >> i >> j >> intensity;
            pic1[i][j] = intensity;
            //cout<<i<<endl
        }
        file1.close();
        //file1.clear();
    }
    else {
      cout << "Error, cannot open file 1"; }

    cout << "Reading in file 2" << endl;    

    if (file1_2.is_open())
      {
        file1_2.seekg(0);
        while (!file1_2.eof())
          {
        file1_2 >> i >> j >> intensity; //
        pic1_2[i][j] = intensity;
          }
        file1_2.close();
        //file1_2.clear();
        //cout<<i<<endl;
      }
    else {
      cout << "Error, cannot open file 1_2"; }

//A LOAD OF CALCULATIONS//
```

Comment: You should run this in the debugger, as that will tell you which line causes the seg-fault.

Comment: ` I get a "segmentation fault" despite it compiling correctly` -- I bet you've _never_ received a segmentation fault on code that did not compile correctly.

Comment: Have you checked the values of `i` and `j` in between? Where do you get the segfault? Have you debugged the program?

Comment: When running one at a time, it reads and stores the arrays correctly and I can display them on my screen. When using both, it won't even let me display any part of the code. It just faults straight away.

Comment: @fiz, that's correct when you don't read the second file, compiler optimizes out the second array and stack therefore doesn't get overflown

Comment: Sorry, in simple terms =P ?

Comment: In simple terms, he meant that if the compiler recognizes you are never actually using (_reading_, not just writing) `pic1_2`, the compiler pretends you never even declared it (and if you write to it without the possibility of reading it, the compiler deletes those accesses too since they're useless). The compiler (optimizer) can easily do this with local variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run your code that reads just a single file, do you only have one array declared or two? Your arrays are both very large and are going to be placed on your application stack, and it's quite normal that stack space cannot grow too large. As a simple test, just move these variables to be globals and see if your crash disappears.

Comment: Glad that helped; it's proven that the problem is using too much stack (local variables). That being done, I would recommend not using globals like this (as a habit, but it's fine for a small program). Instead, I would recommend using some form of dynamic allocation, such as `new` (properly coupled with `delete` to release memory when you no longer need it).

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are getting StackOverflow error

This is too much for the stack:

```
double pic1[1392][1040]; //number of pixels
double pic1_2[1392][1040];
```

Move them outside of `main` function to quickly fix it. Otherwise use dynamic allocation, or even better `std::vector`